# Delete associative table rows when deleting a main model entry

Tags: cakephp, model

I have 2 models, usergroups and usergrouppermissions. my usergrouppermissions has a field called user_group_id which links back to the main usergroup. In a case where I want to delete the user group, I automatically want it to delete the entry in the database for usergrouppermissions (as the user group wont exist) anymore. I have tried delete, however, it just deletes the usergroup.

```
  // Here is my model: (usergroup):
  public $hasMany = array(
       'UserGroupPermission'
  );

  // Here is the usergrouppermissions model:
  public $belongsTo = array(
        "UserGroup"
    );
```

Comment: Look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5712932/cakephp-delete-cascade-not-working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$this->Model->delete($item_to_delete_id,true);
```

[delete() docs.](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/deleting-data.html)